# How do I access a specific element in an Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am having a hard time trying to accessing any elements in my object.

Find below my code that accesses the object from the **localStorage** and prints it out on the browser console:

```
var test = localStorage.getItem('transactionData');
console.log(test);
```

The above code yields:

```
[{Amount":"15,000","payersNumber":"070505788","waitersName":"Agnes"}]
```

When I try to access the element **waitersName** as seen in the code below:

```
console.log(">> " +test.waitersName);
```

It yields:

```
>> undefined
```

How do I access the various elements in my object?

Comment: `test[0].waitersName`

Comment: @zero298 this also yields undefined

Comment: typo in your object, starting quote missing for Amount

Comment: Then try `JSON.parse(test)[0].waitersName`

Comment: @zero298 yes `JSON.parse(test)[0].waitersName` this worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

`test` is an array with an object in it, you'll need to access the array item first with `test[0]` and that will return the object, which will then allow you to access its properties.

Comment: Thanks but if this is what you mean `console.log(">> " +test[0].waitersName);` this yields:  `>> undefined`

Answer (score 1):

The data you retrieve from localstorage is a stringified version of the Javascript array. You first have to parse it using

```
  var array = JSON.parse(test);
```

Then get your elements from the parsed array.